# maven buildnumber plugin only increase buildnumber on specific builds

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I want to increase the buildnumber only on specific builds with the maven-buildnumber-plugin.
I use the standard configuration from the plugins site, e.g.:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
                <format>{0,number}</format>
                <items>
                    <item>buildNumber</item>
                </items>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I only want to execute it at specific builds, so that not all debug builds on my pc increase the number but only the builds done by jenkins change the buildnumber.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we had similar problem with versioning maven, so the solution for us was that we created two separate Jenkins Jobs and we do not use buildnumber-maven-plugin (do not get me wrong , may we did also wronge configuration of plugin, but the fact is that we did not manage to use it in way we want)

anycase, the solution was two separate Jenkins jobs, one for CI (no version increase at all) and other one for Release. For second one we do version in crease inside pipeline script by our self.

Answer (score 0):

You can control that by defining a maven profile. Just increase your version number when you activate this profile.

see https://gist.github.com/michl-b/65797f4b38751c0f7eae678b99b4a3d4 as a similar solution with a different plugin set.

Comment: Nice one. I'll try as soon as I find the time. Although it won't be in the next few weeks